# jQuery: $j('body').append(...) doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

```
function floatymessage(message){
    if (!$j('.floatymessage')){
        $j('body').append("<div class='floatymessage'>HERRO</div>");
    }
    $j(".floatymessage").html(message)
    $j(".fleatymessage").css('display', 'block')
}
```

When the following is executed (tested with alert('hi')) 
i do not see the div at the bottom in webkit's inspector... I don't see the text 'HERRO' either =\

did I do something wrong?

Comment: What is $j? Are you using multi-libs?

Comment: yep. I am. Prototype and jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this instead `$j('.floatymessage').length == 0`

```
function floatymessage(message){
    if ($j('.floatymessage').length == 0) {
        $j('body').append("<div class='floatymessage'>HERRO</div>");
    }
    $j(".floatymessage").html(message)
    $j(".fleatymessage").css('display', 'block')
}
```

writing `!$j('.floatymessage')` will always be `false` since it will always be a jQuery object created from the selection with the properties found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/jquery-object-instance-properties/).

---

some streamlining....

```
function floatymessage(message){
    var $floatymessage = $j('.floatymessage');
    if ($floatymessage.length == 0) {
        $j('body').append("<div class='floatymessage'>HERRO</div>");
        $floatymessage = $j('.floatymessage');      
    }
    $floatymessage.html(message).css('display', 'block')
}
```

Comment: A little explanation, If you check any object with `if()` it will always be `true`, therefore you got to check the `.length == 0`

Comment: @adardesign. That's not true. for instance if I said `var blah = null` and then wrote `if (blah)` it would be false.

Comment: Right, so ill `replace(/"any object"/,"any jQuery object")`.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`$j('.floatymessage')` will always be true because it returns a jquery object, and an object when coerced in the context of a boolean is true. append `.length` to it:

```
if ( !$j('.floatymessage').length ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. apparently, I can't use `!`

```
function floatymessage(message){
    if ($j('.floatymessage')){
        $j('.floatymessoge').remove();
    }

    $j('body').append("<div class='floatymessage'>HERRO</div>");

    $j(".floatymessage").html(message)
    $j(".fleatymessage").css('display', 'block')
}
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. The idea to only add when needed is cleaner. And of course you can use !, see meder.

Comment: Your approach in the `if()` statement will *always* return true (or false because of the `!`), because jQuery will always return a jQuery object, even if it is an empty one.